# Long TTFB from FB Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, http, facebook-graph-api, http-headers

I wrote a **PHP script home-made** in order to get last **FB posts** from a page, which is simply executed from an **jQuery/AJAX** code when my document is ready :
 `$("my_object").load("fb_feed.php");`

Running **on local** PHP server as **on a VPS**, to Time To First Byte is very long : **10s** at least, **20s** on average, or more

```
ini_set("allow_url_fopen", 1);

function getGraphUrl($param){
    return "https://graph.facebook.com/". $param ."access_token=THE_TOKEN";
}
function getContent($param){
    $url = getGraphUrl($param);
    return json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
}
$feed = getContent("ID_OF_THE_PAGE/feed?");
$posts = array();

foreach ($feed->data as $i => $post) {
    if(isset($post->message)){
        $object_id = getContent($post->id . "?fields=object_id&")->object_id;
        if(isset($object_id)){
        $img_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" . $object_id . "/picture";
        $short = (getimagesize($img_url)[1] < 170 ? true : false);
        if($short){
            $img_url = "images/empty.png";
        }
        array_push($posts, array('id' => $post->id,'message' => $post->message,
        'img_url' => $img_url, 'date' => $post->created_time));
        }
    }
    if(count($posts) == 6){
        break;
    }
}
```

The extract of the PHP script which load posts

Everything works, the only problem is the loading duration which is very very long

Is there a way to load faster, rather than build my own cache ?
Is my request poorly made ?

Comment: Are you saying that you are executing this on every single page load? Then yes, of course you should cache the data on your end; not only because of timing issues, but also because otherwise you are likely to run into the API Rate Limits pretty quickly.

Comment: Ok, in this case the problem is solved, thanks